# Проблема с PrettyURL в Yii2 при смене кореневой директории

Tags: php, yii2, .htaccess

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблема с настройкой PrettyURL в Yii2 Advanced. Дело в том, что понадобилось перенести все файлы в директорию app, ранее приложение лежало в кореневой директории и всё работало. Как только перенес его в директорию app - PrettyURL перестали работать.

К примеру, при переходе по URL:

http://site.ru/app/dashboard/settings

Получаю:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /dashboard/settings was not found on this server.

Хотя когда приложение было в кореневой директории - всё работало.

Без PrettyURL всё работает, т.е. по ссылке отображается нужная страница:

http://site.ru/app/frontend/web/index.php?r=dashboard/settings

Настройки, которые я прописал в `frontend/config/main.php`:

```
'request' => [
    'baseUrl' => ''
],
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        '' => 'site/index',
        '<action>' => 'site/<action>',
        '<controller>' => '<controller>/index',

    ],
],
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(backend/web|admin)
RewriteRule !^frontend/web /frontend/web%{REQUEST_URI} [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin(.*) /backend/web/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/frontend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /frontend/web/index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /backend/web/index.php [L]
```

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: А где ваш htaccess лежит?

Comment: @Bookin, папке /app/.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем .htaccess отсутствуют правила для полученного URL, поэтому перенаправления запроса на index.php не происходит. В ваших правилах требуется наличие слова frontend или backend, для перенаправления запросов.

Вероятно проблема как раз в том, что генерируется URL без этих ключевых слов.

Попробуйте заполнить опцию baseUrl в вашей конфигурации:

```
'baseUrl' => '/app/frontend'
```